# How to get HTTPS url to work with Drupal Iframe Module?

Tags: http-request

I want to get HTTPS urls working as iframes. Now only http URL's work.

https://www.drupal.org/project/iframe

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You'll need to do a hook_form_alter to basically change lines `668` and `740` of [iframe.module](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/iframe/tree/iframe.module)

Comment: And what code do I put in there?